# Returning variable from inside try/catch block

Tags: java, arrays, return, try-catch

Good evening guys. Look, I've got this big trouble and see no solution for it, but I know there must be a way to solve this...

```
public static int[] prices() throws Exception {
    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        Statement search = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = search.executeQuery("SELECT nomeProd FROM main;");
        rs.last();
        int k = rs.getRow();
        rs.beforeFirst();
        int prices[] = new int[k];

        /*
        for( int i = 1; i <= k; i++ ) {

        }
        */

        return prices;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

So, what I need is to return the prices array from inside the try-catch block or I won't be able to get the variable "k". If I initialize k as 0 before the try block, and create the array after the catch block, then I won't be able to access the ResultSet variable (well, yes, I could connect, create a statement and resultset all over again but that would probably just cause me more headache).

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just declare your variables outside `try/catch` block, then they will be accessible both inside and outside the block. For example:

```
Connection con = null;
try {
         con = getConnection();
       // rest of code on the same lines

}
```

Comment: So only initializing Connection as null before the try block would do the job?

Comment: @TomásDornasPerone My answer is about how you can broaden the visibility of your variables. setting connection to null , will do no job except declaration of variable with default value as null.

Comment: Thank you, I have declared all variables outside the try/catch,.. now it's all working just fine. Thank you Juned.